# Facebook OAuth2 authentication not working for Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, facebook-graph-api, spring-security, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I am building a spring-boot application which uses google/facebook oauth2 authentication. The application configurations set are as follows:

```java
    #Google
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientId=<googleClientId>
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientSecret=<googleClientSecret>
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirectUri={baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=email,profile
    
    #Facebook
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.clientId=<fbClientId>
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.clientSecret=<fbClientSecret>
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.redirectUri={baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.scope=email,public_profile
    
    spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.facebook.authorizationUri=https://www.facebook.com/v13.0/dialog/oauth
    spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.facebook.tokenUri=https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/oauth/access_token
    spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.facebook.userInfoUri=https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,is_verified,picture.width(250).height(250)
```

For google, this is working well - the application has an authorization rest controller which redirects to the google auth end point. After logging in, I can see a code is returned and sent to a redirect URI {baseUrl}/ouath2/callback/google, which is exchanged for a token which is in turn parsed and used to construct a universal application-level Oauth2 bearer token (for use in my shared APIs etc).

For facebook, I am attempting a similar setup. The initial redirect works, and user is directed to a facebook login page with equivalent client_id / redirect uri parameters set:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth
    ?response_type=code
    &client_id=<fbClientId>
    &scope=email+public_profile
    &state=<state>
    &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F192.168.50.150.nip.io%3A8300%2Foauth2%2Fcallback%2Ffacebook
    &ret=login
    &fbapp_pres=0
    &logger_id=e1036c5a-ac6e-448c-ab8g-655727eae993
    &tp=unspecified
    &cbt=1643459835928
    &ext=1645463198
    &hash=AeJog6HeUz9jlsDRQQo
```

However, when the code is obtained after login and sent to the redirect uri {baseUrl}/ouath2/callback/facebook, there is an error returned when my application attempts to access the FB User Info resource server:

[image: Network traffic 1]

[image: Network Traffic 2]

I don't have any traffic capture from my backend to the FB User Info URI, so I can't see exactly what's being sent, but the response I get back is a server error:

> [invalid_user_info_response] An error occurred while attempting to
> retrieve the UserInfo Resource: Error details: [UserInfo Uri:
> https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,is_verified,picture.width(250).height(250),
> Error Code: server_error]

Are there any known issues with the graph.facebook.com end points?

Comment: Trying that same request in Graph API Explorer (same for as far as it will accept, API version v3.0 is so very old, it isn't even available as a choice there any more, lowest is v6.0), I am getting an error _"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (is_verified) on node type (User)"_

Comment: That was it! Removing "is_verified" query param fixed everything. Works for all versions of graph API I've tried, but have upgraded to v13.0 anyway. For anyone reading, worth noting I am using spring-boot version 2.6.5. Any lower versions I've tried had separate issues during code/token exchange

Comment: I've since tried as low as 2.2.1.RELEASE and I'm not having any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change v13 to v17, and remove field `is_verified`

old

```java
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.facebook.userInfoUri=https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,is_verified,picture.width(250).height(250)
```

new

```java
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.facebook.userInfoUri=https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,picture.width(250).height(250)
```

You can test at link like this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cfirst_name%2Cmiddle_name%2Clast_name%2Cname%2Cemail%2Cverified%2Cpicture.width(250).height(250)&version=v17.0

[image]

Related useful config can see at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blame/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/oauth2/client/CommonOAuth2Provider.java